# NULL IN (1,2,NULL) returns false

Tags: sql

Why does this SQL-statement return `0`?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL IN (9,1,NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Because `NULL = NULL` is `NULL`

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48643/query-to-find-guids-not-in-null-containing-subquery-returns-no-results/

Comment: Don't migrate this to DBA.stackexchange. It's too basic and we've already addressed it so it'd simply be closed as a duplicate

Comment: From your previous question you are on SQL Server. You can do `SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT NULL INTERSECT SELECT C FROM (VALUES(9),(1),(NULL)) V(C)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what RDBMS you are using since some of them has configuration on how `NULL` will be treated.

```
NULL IN (9, 1, NULL)
```

can be written as

```
(NULL = 9) OR (NULL = 1) OR (NULL = NULL)
```

and not of them were `TRUE` nor `FALSE`. They are all `NULL`. Since there are only two paths in the `CASE` statement, it falls under `ELSE` block.

Answer (score 3):

SQL is based on [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), where there are three truth values: `TRUE`, `FALSE`, and `UNKNOWN`. The special `NULL` value is a placeholder for "missing data"  and if you compare something, anything, with missing data the result is unknown.

For example, is `<missing data>` equal to `<missing data>`? It's impossible to know, so the result is `UNKNOWN`.

In this particular case, you are trying to find out if `<missing data>` is in a given list: since the data is missing, it's impossible to know if it's in the list, and the query returns `0`.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL IN (9,1,NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how `NULL` is treated in the specific server.

For instance in SQL SERVER you may set ANSI_NULLS off and have it return 1:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

SELECT CASE WHEN NULL IN (9,1,NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

For further info you should read the remarks section of [`SET ANSI_NULLS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't compare `null` values using comparison operators. You can only use `is null` or `is not null` or using functions like `COALESCE()`, `ISNULL()`. For example

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(NULL,-1) IN (9,1,-1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Null mean not defined.

NUll object is not equal to other NULL

NULL==1 return false

NUll==2 return false

**NULL==NULL return also false**